# c++ windows keep track of file writes by processes

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

I need to track the creation/reading/writing/... of files by processes.
Tell me how can I implement this?
I found the ReadDirectoryChanges function, but it doesn't give the process name.

windows, C ++

Comment: Inject into every process (maybe via SetWindowsHookEx), and hook `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`.

Comment: Write a custom [file system filter device driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/about-file-system-filter-drivers) to get the information.  That is what [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) does (see [The Ultimate Guide to Procmon: Filter Drivers](https://adamtheautomator.com/procmon/#Filter_Drivers)).

Comment: I just checked Process Monitor no longer uses PROCMON24 instead of talking to FltMgr (\FileSystem\Filteres\FltMgrMsg).